# Python 2.7.5, list basics, displaying list input properly

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Just started venturing into arrays using python 2.7.5. My objective is to ask the user for input and store the input in multiple arrays.

So far this is what I have, as far as storing multiple arrays with input. I run into an error when trying to print the input at the end.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
# want user to enter a list of employee names, error occurs when trying to recall user entry

emp_name = [0] 
emp_name = raw_input("please enter employee name") 

while emp_name !="neg":
    emp_name = raw_input("please enter employee name,enter neg to exit")

print "employee 2 is:", emp_name[1] #I want the 2nd name entered to appear
```

Comment: You are creating `list` objects, not arrays. There is a subtle difference, especially since there is a Python `array` module and the `numpy` project also has arrays. Lists can contain different types, arrays are meant to hold *one* type only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line declares `emp_name` as an array.

Your second line `raw_input("please enter employee name")` re-assigns it as a string.

So when you tell it to `print emp_name[1]`, it has no idea what `emp_name[1]` is because it sees a string at that point.

If you write, instead:

```
emp_name[0] = raw_input("please enter employee name")
```

That means you're assigning that employee name to *element 0* of *array* `emp_name`.

Then you want to *add index entries* inside the `while`, rather than re-assigning them (you see, it doesn't automatically accumulate entries, you have to tell it to).

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

Then you are going to want to:

1. Change the names of your variables so that you don't have the list be the same name as the input.
2. Append each name you get to the list.

This should be what you want:

```
employees = []
name = raw_input("Please enter an employee name: ") 

while name != "neg":
    # Append the previous name.
    employees.append(name)
    # Get a new name.
    name = raw_input("Please enter an employee name or 'neg' to exit: ")

# You need a try/except here in case there is no second employee.
# This can happen if the user types in "neg" to begin with or only 1 name.
try:
    print "Employee 2 is: ", employees[1]
except IndexError:
    print None
```

Also, I slightly changed your input prompts to make them cleaner and more user-friendly.

Below is a sample of the script in action:

```
Please enter an employee name: Bob
Please enter an employee name or 'neg' to exit: Joe
Please enter an employee name or 'neg' to exit: neg
Employee 2 is:  Joe
```

And here is one without a second employee:

```
Please enter an employee name: Joe
Please enter an employee name or 'neg' to exit: neg
Employee 2 is:  None
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add to a list with `list.append()`, but you need to capture user input into a *separate* variable:

```
employees = []
emp_name = raw_input("Please enter employee name, enter neg to exit")

while emp_name != "neg":
    emp_name = raw_input("Please enter employee name, enter neg to exit")
    employees.append(emp_name)

print "employee 2 is:", employees[1]
```

Apart from using separate variables for the list of names and for the name the user has just entered, I also started the list entirely empty.

You can avoid using two `raw_input()` calls by changing the `while` loop to an infinite loop and instead break *out* of the loop when `'neg'` has been entered:

```
employees = []

while True:
    emp_name = raw_input("Please enter employee name, enter neg to exit")
    if emp_name == 'neg':
        break
    employees.append(emp_name)
```

You may also need to test if there are enough employees entered before you print the second employee:

```
if len(employees) > 1:
    print "Employee 2 is:", employees[1] 
else:
    print "You didn't enter enough employees!"
```

Comment: What happens if the user types in "neg" to begin with?  This will throw an `IndexError` right?